# How to register type adapter for boolean.class/Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType and Boolean.class/Boolean.class.java

Tags: kotlin, gson, code-conversion

I am trying to convert this Java sample into Kotlin:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean.class, new JsonStrictBooleanDeserializer())
        .registerTypeAdapter(boolean.class, new JsonStrictBooleanDeserializer())
        .create();
```

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean::class.java, JsonStrictBooleanDeserializer())
        .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType, JsonStrictBooleanDeserializer())
        .create()
```

However, they do not appear to behave the same. I decompiled the Kotlin sample and it appears that only one type adapter is being registered:

```
(new GsonBuilder())
        .registerTypeAdapter((Type)Boolean.TYPE, new JsonStrictBooleanDeserializer())
        .registerTypeAdapter((Type)Boolean.TYPE, new JsonStrictBooleanDeserializer())
        .create();
```

What is the correct way of registering a type adapter for boxed and primitive booleans in Kotlin?

Comment: Are you aware of this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374546/can-i-somehow-see-what-i-commented-or-answered-to-a-question-deleted-by-author ?

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you for notifying about ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both uses of the `Boolean` class you have are being compiled to the primitive boolean type. You need to use [`javaObjectType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-object-type.html) in addition to [`javaPrimitiveType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-primitive-type.html), like so:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean::class.javaObjectType, JsonStrictBooleanDeserializer())
        .registerTypeAdapter(Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType, JsonStrictBooleanDeserializer())
        .create()
```

This will result in the first call using `Boolean.class` and the second using `Boolean.TYPE` (the `Class` for the primitive `boolean`).